# Moto G7 Plus Pixel OS 12 Cannot Pass SafetyNet check

Tags: magisk, safety-net

I have a Moto G7 Plus.
I installed the Pixel OS 12 Plus. I installed Magisk 25.1. I enabled both Zygisk and Enforce DenyList. In the DenyList, I only selected the Google Play Services, enabled all the items except com.google.android.gms.

I rebooted and installed module MagiskHidePropsConf-v6.1.2.zip. Rebooted and installed module safetynet-fix-Zygisk-v2.2.1.zip. Rebooted and use the terminal to change the props to Google Nexus 6P.
Rebooted, run Root Checker. It shows SafetyNet request Failed. CTS profile match N/A. Basic integrity N/A.
What else can I do to pass the safetynet?

Comment: Uninstall all modules, reboot, install [USNF](https://github.com/kdrag0n/safetynet-fix), check for Safety net using [YASNAC](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=RIKKA.SAFETYNETCHECKER) // If you still can't clear, try with MagiskHideProps module (with USNF installed)

Comment: Apart from that try some other device to spoof

Comment: I did not do anything, just use YASNAC to check and it shows "Something went wrong Attestation response timeout"

Comment: Start with a clean slate (uninstall all modules) as I first said and go about it as suggested